# Editing Global Action - New Case layout

Tags: page-layout, case-object, global-actions

Where do I go to edit the fields on the Global Action - New Case?

I've checked Global Actions in the settings menu and it doesn't appear there, nor is it on the Cases Object.  I want to add a custom field to the pop out screen

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can go to **Setup > Create > Global Actions > Global Actions** then click "layout" action link on New Case.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but I went here and there is no New Case global action.  Only SendEmail, CreateNewContact and NewGroup